# Is it possible to change pgAdmin SQL completion shortcut?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pgAdmin SQL query editor, the default SQL code completion shortcut is `ctrl-space`; however, my native language is not English, we use `ctrl-space` to switch input method.

Is it possible to change this completion shortcut to something else, such as `tab` or `alt-/`?

(Although I think pgAdmin is good enough, if there's good alternative, I would also be glad to know.)